# How can I use an inbuilt function in R to make my code more effective (for loops)?

Tags: r, for-loop

So I have a dataframe with some rows that have NA values. I want to detect if a row has a NA value and write out in a new column if that row is NA or not. So I did a standard double for loop to solve it. My question is, can I do this more effective with an inbuilt R function? My code works but if I have a larger data frame it will be tedious to do this

my code:

```
for (j in 1:ncol(test)) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
        if (is.na(test[i,j])) {
            test$NA[i] <- "NA value"
        }
        else {
            test$NA[i] <- "No NA value"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `test$NA <- c("No NA value", "NA value")[1+as.integer(apply(is.na(test),1, any))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()`:

```
set.seed(42)
test <- matrix(sample(c(3:12, NA), 20, repl=TRUE), 5)
test <- as.data.frame(test)
test$`NA` <- c("No NA value", "NA value")[1 + apply(is.na(test), 1, any)]
test
#   V1 V2 V3 V4          NA
# 1 NA  8  8 NA    NA value
# 2 NA 11 10 NA    NA value
# 3  6  4 NA  4    NA value
# 4 12 10  5  8 No NA value
# 5 10 10  8  9 No NA value
```

naming the new column "NA" is not a good idea because `NA` is predefined in `R`. If you don't need the lables in the new column you can use

```
test$NAindicator <- apply(is.na(test), 1, any)
```

You can also preserve `test` as a matrix:

```
set.seed(42)
test <- matrix(sample(c(3:12, NA), 20, repl=TRUE), 5)
test <- cbind(test, apply(is.na(test), 1, any))
test
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   NA    8    8   NA    1
# [2,]   NA   11   10   NA    1
# [3,]    6    4   NA    4    1
# [4,]   12   10    5    8    0
# [5,]   10   10    8    9    0
```

or you can put it in a list:

```
list(mat=test, NAindicator=apply(is.na(test), 1, any))
```

Comment: Thank you all! But what does this line do? 
[1+apply

I get the apply part but not the +1

Comment: @arezaie `as.integer(FALSE)` is 0, `as.integer(TRUE)` is 1. Indices in R have to begin with 1 (for indexing the vector `c("No NA value", "NA value")`).

Comment: Thank you! Appriciate the help/lesson!

Answer (score 2):

If I read your double loop correctly, you want to label each row in your data frame as `NA value` if `NA` occurs at least once in that row, otherwise label `No NA value`.  You can use a few base R functions here to do this, including `rowSums()` and `is.na()`:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,NA,2), v2=c(1,2,3), v3=c(1,2,NA))
df$nav[rowSums(is.na(df)) == 0] <- "No NA value"
df$nav[rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0] <- "NA value"
> df
  v1 v2 v3         nav
1  1  1  1 No NA value
2 NA  2  2    NA value
3  2  3 NA    NA value
```

Note that I renamed your `NA` column to `nav` to avoid collision with `na`, which has a special meaning in R.

Comment: Also, `ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0, "NA value", "No NA value")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `Reduce`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, NAV := c("No NA value", "NA value")[is.na(Reduce(`+`, .SD)) + 1]] 
test
#   V1 V2 V3 V4         NAV
#1: NA  8  8 NA    NA value
#2: NA 11 10 NA    NA value
#3:  6  4 NA  4    NA value
#4: 12 10  5  8 No NA value
#5: 10 10  8  9 No NA value
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
test$NAV <- paste(sub("\\d+", "No NA", do.call(pmax, test)), "value")
test$NAV
#[1] "NA value"    "NA value"    "NA value"    "No NA value" "No NA value"
```